# Git branch un-usable after having an '&' in its name

Tags: git, branch

So I created a git branch with an `&` within its name. Only realizing later that using a '&' on a git branch is actually a command of some kind.

So, now i've come into a situation where I cannot get into the branch....additionally I cannot delete the branch or remove it.

I am wondering if anyone would know what to do to get around this?

My branch name is

`FE-prompt-for-H&W`

When i try to get into it i get an error message stating. (this also is the same error i see when i try to delete it).

`error: pathspec 'FE-prompt-for-H' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Would anyone have any ideas on how to take care of this issue here?

Comment: if you do git branch --list, what does it say? I just created a test repo, created a branch "Test-H&W", and it gave me a branch "Test-H", I went back to master and did `git branch -d Test-H` and that worked

Comment: If you want to include a `&` in a branch, you have to quote it; otherwise the shell interprets it as a command separator. `git branch H&W` creates a branch named `H` *in the background*, then (most  likely) complains that no command `W` was found. `git branch "H&W"` would create the branch as desired.

Comment: You need to do the same for `git checkout "H&W"`, `git branch -d "H&W"`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git itself has no prohibition on using `&` in a branch name. Protecting the `&` fro the shell is another matter.

To pass the literal name `Test-H&W` to any `git` command, you need to quote it. For example,

```
git checkout "Test-H&W"
```

Left unquoted, the *shell* treats `&` as a command terminator, indicating the command should be run in the background.

```
git checkout Test-H&W
```

tries to run `git` in the background, then run the command `W`. `git` will fail because you don't have a branch named `Test-H`, and `W` will fail if you don't have a command named `W`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make my comment an answer since it worked when I tried it. When you created the branch "FE-prompt-for-H&W", it successfully created a branch called "FE-prompt-for-H"

if you are on a different branch, run `git branch -d FE-prompt-for-H` to delete it